# ionice or chrt for Bonnie benchmark

Tags: linux, performance-tuning, linux-kernel, embedded

I am running Bonnie benchmark on an embedded device and I am getting variable results for every run. I am contemplating using ionice and / or chrt to get around it. Can you suggest which option is better ? ionice or chrt ?

Answer (score 0):

What kernel and distribution are you using? Are you on a realtime kernel?

I typically don't use `ionice` because it never seems to work when used in conjunction with the kernel elevator settings in my setups (only for CFQ). However, you can try a run of Bonnie++ with something like: `chrt -f 75 bonnie++` to use the FIFO scheduler with realtime priority 75. Repeat with realtime priority 95.